# Will The Normal Forces Be Equal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

A block of mass m slides down an inclined right angled trough and the coefficient of friction between block and the trough is μ.

[image: A block of mass m slides down an inclined right angled trough.]

My Book Says that the Normal Forces will be equal from either side of the trough , but I think they will be different because the trough makes an angle of θ with one side and (90-θ) with the other and thus after some calculation, I am getting the Normal Forces as different, one as “mg sinθ” and other as “mg cosθ”.

What is the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: It's hard to see from the diagram what exactly $\theta$ is. is it the angle between the edge and the horizontal? Between one side of the trough and the horizontal?

Comment: Good golly, that's a bad illustration. That's from the book?

Comment: @KristofferSjöö Yes,it is.That’s the exact diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture suggests that there is a mirror symmetry about the vertical plane through the edge, with $\theta$ being the angle between the edge and horizontal plane:

[image]

Comment: ... and because of this symmetry, the normal force would be equal on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've misinterpreted what angle is being denoted in the figure - it's the angle between the horizontal ground and the bottom *edge* of the trough, not between the ground and one of the *faces* of the trough. The trough itself is symmetric about the vertical axis, so it's not "tilted" to one side or the other.

If the trough were tilted, you'd be correct that the normal forces from either side would be different. You can imagine in the limit of the trough being an upright "L" shape, the vertical wall produces no normal force at all, and the situation is equivalent to a block just sliding down a flat board.